# How do attacks work for 3.0 monsters

Tags: dnd-3e, attack

I was looking through the monster manual 2 to see if any monster would be good to add to my game (don't worry, I got the 3.5 update). What the update doesn't explain is how attacks work. Right now I'm looking at a greenvise, and in the attack entry it says 4 slams and 1 bite. It seems self explanatory, but I'm confused if that is a standard attack action or a full attack action. Looking in the section about reading the statistics block only mentioned it was an attack routine, and monsters could only use them once per turn. I feel like they're full attacks, but I want to make sure.

Are they regular attacks or full attacks?

Answer (score 5):

By default, a creature can make **one** of its attacks as a Standard action and can make **all** of its attacks as a Full Round Action.

Unless the creature has a special ability that lets it make multiple attacks in a standard action, it can use *either* a single slam or a bite attack as a standard action.